# I need a very specific selector for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys i have a problem with a selector of jquery.

I have this Html:

```
<div id="Id_Province_chzn">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-default" tabindex="-1">
    <span> + this.default_text + 
    </span>
    <div>
        <b></b>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="chzn-drop" style="left:-9000px;">
    <div class="chzn-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <ul class="chzn-results"> **<-- I need to access here**
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to append `<li>` to the `<ul>` tag, but i don't know how to access.
My idea is to do something like this:

```
var ul = $(??);
ul.append('<li>some text</li>');
```

Sorry my english and thanks for your help.

Comment: Without knowing how many `class="chzn-results"` it is impossible to answer. For this sort of work, it may be better to add an `id`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be found in [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: The problem is that this generates automatically. I forget to explain that. for each <select> i have in the document, generate this code. I'm using a template that I bought. The first div is the only one that have an Id

Comment: If you need just the first that fits that selector, use the :first pseudoclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the class selector

```
$('ul.chzn-results').append(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('ul.chzn-results')` should do it.

Comment: The space between the two would make it find a child of the UL with that class... You need to remove the space.